# Discord.NET run multiple bots from one console app project

Tags: c#, .net, discord.net

I've seen many examples how to run Discord.NET Bot but all those examples show how to run 1 bot per 
1 console app project or one bot sharded with servers so is this library designed only for 1<-->1 approach because I saw also singleton is used for connecting part? Is it possible to run multiple bots from one codebase? I need this to keep track bots/connectons and see statuses in webapplication but it might be bad decision if I go with multiple console applications approach.

Comment: Hey there, it might be a good idea to edit your question and add some code that illustrates what you're trying to do, and where you're getting stuck!

Comment: All u need to do is login to multiple DiscordSocketClients or Sharded clients within the program.

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to understand how can I model the whole system, but yeah regarding those mutiple clients DiscordSocketClients than I need somewhere to store and keep safetly might be concurent dictionary or something else and this storage shouldn't be disposed for long term

Comment: but that memory storage for clients can grow maybe its not best way for scaling but cannot find another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use object and class for each discord bot though but I wanted to give you idea of how can you achieve such an effect. I would probably also use better logging system (maybe some logging library?). But if I were you I would think maybe about using docker and docker-compose?

Cheers

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;

namespace temp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Bot1(Func<LogMessage, Task> log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            client.Log += log;
            await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "token1");
            await client.StartAsync();
            await Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken);
        }
        public static async Task Bot2(Func<LogMessage, Task> log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            client.Log += log;
            await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "token2");
            await client.StartAsync();
            await Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken);
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, args) =>
            {
                cancellationToken.Cancel();
                args.Cancel = true;
            };
            Task.WhenAll(new Task[]
            {
                Bot1(Log, cancellationToken.Token),
                Bot2(Log, cancellationToken.Token)
            });
        }

        private static async Task Log(LogMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for example! Yeah I could also think about docker compose but for now I need simple solution